# how to set every divs background as its inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have

```
<div class="container">red</div>
<div class="container">green</div>
<div class="container">#eeeeee</div>
```

and I want to set Background color for each div of what its inner HTML have
like the first div`s background color must be red and the second ones will be green. and soo on

I don't want to use CSS because I have more than 50 divs so its long code in CSS
and I'm a beginner in javascript is there any way we can do this with some lines of code.

Comment: Yeh sure... is there a particular order of colours for the 50 items? And can you use the same colour more than once?

Comment: no sir @AdamJeffers , its random and can be changed in future. and yessame color more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

**jQuery**

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background', $(this).text());
});
```

**JS**

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) 
{
  elems[i].style.backgroundColor = elems[i].innerText;
}
```

Comment: Output : `referenceError : color not defined`

Comment: duplicate of my answer :)

Comment: haha, you are right. Pretty simple answer though.... and great minds obviously think alike!

Comment: @AdamJeffers can you write this in javascript?

Comment: Yes does it need to be then?

Comment: Haha, just added some JS... but its the same as @Rory's.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `css()` method for this:

```js
$('div.container').css('background-color', function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">red</div>
<div class="container">green</div>
<div class="container">#eeeeee</div>
```

Native JS version:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.container');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.backgroundColor = elements[i].innerText;
}
```

Comment: @victor That can be written. But why did you tag this question in jquery?

Comment: Strangely, this makes it failed: `<div class="container">chucknorris</div>`??? I guess related to `css()` jq method but i don't know why?!

Comment: i was just in hurry, sorry.  can you post it in javascript also.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ya, i get fooled by the bgcolor attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/s63hL09f/1

Comment: @victor I added a pure JS version for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OMG, your edit is as same as my new answer. Removing my dup. Glad i had the same thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should help :)

```
$(".container").each(function (){
    $(this).css('background', $(this).text());
});
```

**Update** based on your comment

Pure JS version:

If you're developing website for **modern browsers** you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
for(var i=0;i<containers.length;i++){
   containers[i].style.background = containers[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Or you can use this function for **old browsers**.

```
function getElementsByClassName(cn, rootNode) {
    if (!rootNode) {
        rootNode = document;
    } 
    for (var r=[], e=rootNode.getElementsByTagName('*'), i=e.length; i--;) {
        if ((' '+e[i].className+' ').indexOf(' '+cn+' ')>-1) {
          r.push(e[i]); 
        }
    }
    return r;  
}

var containers = getElementsByClassName('container');
for(var i=0;i<containers.length;i++){
   containers[i].style.background = containers[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each function

```js
$('.container').each(function(){
    var color = $(this).text();
    $(this).css('background',color)
})
```

```css
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">red</div>
<div class="container">green</div>
<div class="container">#eeeeee</div>
```